# How can I move a OneDrive folder to external hard drive?

Tags: onedrive

I’m running out of space in SSD and have bought external hdd, but there is no section showing where to move to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to do it is by:

First ensure that your OneDrive is Up-To-Date synced with local.

1. unlinking your drive to OneDrive
2. Move the folder you want to the desired location
3. Re-link the folder to OneDrive account

   4. It's ok to merge, as the sync will read all your files as being the latest ones in the cloud. It does this by checking the MD5/SHA hashes of the files and ensures they are the same that is on the cloud.

That's the easiest way!

Answer (score 0):

- download OneDrive for Desktop - **https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-en/download/**
- install it
- a folder shall be created where you can drop your files

Comment: I already have files on computer, just tried re link file after unlink. Seemed to work good